# change event dont execute after running a hotkey event on an input element - jquery

Tags: jquery, onchange, jquery-hotkeys

at below code in the input element after I write something .chane() event will execute Normally.

but when I use a hotkey event such as left key and change the input value the change() event will not work until I change the input value Manually.

why?

how to execute change() event on an input element after changing its value by a function ?

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

    $('input').change(function(){
        console.log('changed');
    }).bind('keydown', 'left', function(){
        $(this).val('test message');
    });

});
</script>

<input type="text" />
```

Comment: `$(this).val('test message').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0):

You could manually trigger the change event

```
$(function(){

    $('input').change(function(){
        console.log('changed');
    }).bind('keydown', 'left', function(){
        $(this).val('test message');
        $(this).change();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe for the format.  Clearly that was my first time submitting an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

we can use this too :

```
$(function(){

    $('input').change(function(){
        console.log('changed');
        $(this).unbind('keydown.manuallbind');
    }).bind('keydown', 'left', function(){
        $(this).val('test message').blur(function(){
            $(this).change();
        }).bind('keydown.manuallbind','return',function(){
            $(this).change();
        });
    });

});
```

advantages of this rule is that .change() event executes such as when we change input value manually.